# ajax is not working properly with forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have some issues regarding form submission using ajax. When I am enclosing input tags with the form tag its not working. When I remove the form tag nothing is happening. What could be the reason?

**HTML:**

```
<form id="leaveform" action="" method="POST">
    <label > Add Type Of leave </label>
    <input type="text" id="typename" name="typename" placeholder="Enter Type" /> 
    <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantityleaves" placeholder="Enter Quantity" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="sub" id="sub" value="submit"/>               
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#sub").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){
            $("#successfull").fadeIn();         
        }       
    });
});
```

Comment: show test.php code

Comment: You can open network and check if a request is going. Also, check console for any errors.

Comment: Are you saying that the values of input tags are not getting submitted to the php code?

Comment: I think control is not moving to ajax part of the code, after click event, nothing is happenning, for php file, its simple file to check whether connection with ajax is working or not: php file <?php

include 'databaseConnect.php'; // database connection file
echo 'hi'; 

?>

Comment: I think you are using `<input type="submit"` in that form, which will trigger a form submission on click, please change that to `<input type="button"`

Answer (score 0):

its because `$("#sub").click(function(){ }` not working properly,
 when its inside the form try using this

`$("#leaveform #sub").click(function(){ }`

Comment: Is there any reason of charecter encoding , in console it was showing charecter enocding error, but when i used , <meta charset="utf-8"> even then its not working

Comment: try using as       $("#leaveform #sub").click(function(){ }

Answer (score 0):

Try using `event.preventDefault()` before your ajax call as below:

```
$("#sub").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){
            $("#successfull").fadeIn();
       }       
   });
});
```

Comment: Adding a brief explanation of event.preventDefault(); would be really cool. Maybe even a link with more details or something.

Comment: The issue is bcz when you the click event of submit button is called it will submit the form on the url specified in form's action attribute. In your case it is the same page. So, when you click on submit, before your ajax is called your form's action is called, hence nothing is happening.

event.preventDefault is used to prevent execution of default action of event.


you can refer the detailed documentation here : https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 0):

first you have to change "type" of button tag "submit" to "button" in your form

```
<form>
...
 <button type="button" name="sub" id="sub" value="submit"/> 
</form>
```

remember one thing , type="submit" will reload the page , where as type="button" not reload

next in your script,

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"/>

 <script>
 $(document).on('click','#sub',function(){
  var typename=$('#typename').val();
  var quantity =$('#quantity').val();

  $.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "POST",
    data:{typename: typename, quantityleaves:quantity}
    success: function(data){
        alert("Successful");
   }       
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: the src code for jaquery is available in the header file,

Answer (score 0):

try this script

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sub").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                $("#successfull").fadeIn();         
            }       
        });
    });

});
```

i think you are missing the ready function , it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#leaveform").on('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){
            $("#successfull").fadeIn();         
        }       
    });
});
```

TRY this code. With this code you can manipulate the data inside the form very well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use document.ready. I have tried and is working.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#sub").click(function(event){
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){
            $("#successfull").fadeIn();         
        }       
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```